# How to get php -r to output on OSX command line

Tags: php, macos, unix, command-line-interface

I am trying to run something like

```
php -r 'echo "test"'
```

on the Mac OSX command line. It throws no error, in fact nothing happens at all.

How can I get it to output "test" on the command line?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a semi-colon to mark the end of the command, i.e.

```
php -r 'echo "test";'
```

(or

```
php -r 'echo "test\n";'
```

to move to a new line.)